# Imported asc-file has huge off-set

Tags: coordinate-system, ascii

I'm fairly new to QGIS but thought I kinda got the CRS issues. I'm using version 2.8.3 on Windows.

However I'm currently trying to import an asc-file from the German weather service.  The problem is that the layer has- once imported- a terrible offset.  The map with wind-data of Germany is suddenly located over the black sea.

I've tried all things I could find. Predefining the CRS-System, with ->setting->options, assign projection, tried out several different crs, but it all won't work.

The file description from the weather service says it is

> Gauss-Kruger-Projection with reference meridian 9 degree east (Bessel-Ellipsoid)

But I have no idea what to do with this information since I can't find this CRS among the offerer CRS.

Here you can find the files, which are giving me problems. It's the last asc-file in the folder: [ftp-cdc.dwd.de](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/multi_annual/wind_parameters/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [EPSG code](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31467/) for your data is **31467**. Source for this information is [this website](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=eng&gdz_akt_zeile=6&gdz_anz_zeile=3). It's other name seems to be "DHDN / Gauss-Kruger zone 3". When asked to enter the projection, type in this code in the Filter area and you'll find your projection easily.

[image]

*"Gauß-Krüger-Projection in the nten meridian strip - Ellipsoid Bessel 
Datum Potsdam (origin of Rauenberg) (strip 2 to 5: central meridians 6, 9, 12, 15 degrees)"*

It tried on one of the files, it fits real fine :

[image]